# Unity - How to change sprite size to fixed resoltion in code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bitmap, sprite, resolution

I have a set of sprites with different resolutions and aspect ratios. I want to create new sprites based on the original sprites but with a fixed 20 x 20 resolution.

When working with bitmaps, what I did was this: `Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(oldImage, new Size(20, 20));`

But Unity's Sprites don't have any constructors. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to create Sprites from image or original sprite.
from image code below..

```
string url = "";//image url;
WWW image = new WWW(url);
yield return image;
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
image.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
Sprite newSprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0), 1);
RectTransform rt = newSprite.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rt.sizeDelta = new Vector2(20, 20);//make 20px * 20px sprite
```

clone sprite code below..

```
Sprite cloneSprite = Instantiate(originalSprite);
RectTransform rt = cloneSprite.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rt.sizeDelta = new Vector2(20, 20);//make 20px * 20px sprite
```

I hope it will work on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly you want to resize an image (make it smaller, or cut the part of it), but you can play around with `Sprite.Create` method